# Verificar los nombres exactos de los servicios que se están ejecutando

Tags: linux, bash

La instrucción

```
if (ps ax | grep -v grep | grep 'php' > /dev/null)
```

da verdadero para los servicios

`php` y `php-fpm7.2`

y cualquier servicio que empiece por 'php'.

¿Cómo puedo modificar la instrucción para que de verdadero sólo y exactamente para php?

```
'php ' (espacio al final)
```

no funcionó... sigue mostrando como verdadero `php-fpm7.2...`

```
uname -v # muestra
1 SMP Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El comando `pgrep` puede servirte de mucha ayuda.
Busca procesos basados en un patrón.

Por ejemplo, si tienes dos procesos, uno que se llama `php` y otro que se llama `php-fpm7.2` corriendo.

Puedes utilizar:

```
$ pgrep "php|php-fpm7.2"
469
498
```

O simplemente `pgrep "php"` puesto que ambos comparten la cadena "php".

Si sólo quieres uno de los dos, haz uso de las expresiones regulares.

```
$ pgrep "^php$"
808
```

En este caso se indica que la cadena "php" se encuentra entre el caracter nulo en el inicio (`^`) y caracter nulo al final (`$`), osea, que sea "php" a secas.

Si quieres que te devuelva 0 o diferente de 0, puedes utilizar la misma estrategia con

```
$ [[ $(pgrep "^php$") ]] && echo Verdadero || echo Falso
Verdadero
```

Pero, volviendo a tu pregunta, los "nombres exactos" se responde con la expresión regular "^palabra$". Entonces, si nos volvemos a los comandos que estabas usando en el inicio. La forma de usarlos sería semejante.

```
$ ps ax | grep -v grep | grep '^php$' # Nota que incluí las "anclas de posición"
```

El problema que veo en esta última aproximación, es que el resultado del comando `ps ax` va a marcar el resultado de la expresión regular como "Falso", ya que iniciaría con algo de la forma.

```
808 tty3     S      0:00 php etc etc
```

Y eso no es precisamente el comando `php`, para ese caso, la linea adecuada sería dejando el caracter nulo al final y quitando la indicación de el caracter nulo al inicio.

```
$ ps ax | grep -v grep | grep 'php$'
```

Comment: Funcionó perfecto, gracias...

Comment: Que bien, si te funcionó, no olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada y/o emitir un voto positivo. Para que las personas que tengan dudas semejantes puedan saber si funcionó.